# Server.Execute() executes click handler again after calling asp file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, winnovative

I'm trying to generate a PDF using Winnovative Tools. In my click handler which fires after clicking on the "Print PDF button", I have the code below.

I expect control to resume to the printPDF_Click sub routine after calling Server.Execute() but instead it calls the printPDF_Click sub routine from scratch which causes a loop because Server.Execute() will be called again and so on.

It works as expected when I set **preserveForm** as **False** but then I lose my form data and the point is retaining it.

```
Private Sub printPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles printPDF.Click
    Dim outTextWriter As IO.TextWriter = New IO.StringWriter()

    Server.Execute("Default_v3.aspx?isWinnovative=true", outTextWriter)

    Dim baseUrl As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
    Dim htmlStringToConvert As String = outTextWriter.ToString()


    Dim downloadBytes As Byte() = PdfHelper.CreatePdf(htmlStringToConvert, baseUrl)

    Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
    response.Clear()
    response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream")
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment; filename=" + (
                     "Rendered.pdf" + ("; size=" + downloadBytes.Length.ToString))))
    response.Flush()
    response.BinaryWrite(downloadBytes)
    response.Flush()
    response.End()
End Sub
```

Comment: `Server.Execute` is not what you need to do. What you should do is call a function which creates the data.

Comment: @AndrewMorton How should I do it then? I need to retain the data on the controls (form data) to render the page as string

Comment: Which page do you need to render: the current one or "Default_v3.aspx"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Current one is "Default_v3.aspx" It's a single page.

Comment: Can't have code running on a page, and then decide to load to another page. Now if you move the code outside of that one page - say in a standard code module, then sure, but if you change the current page, then of course you can't touch the controls on that page.  You could however drop in a iframe on the current page, and that iframe could point to the other page that you load up. So you have to move out that code to a callable sub. you NEVER load a page to JUST call some code on that page - move that code out to a stadnard callable sub, and call it like any other sub routine call you make